# Physics: mesh moving on top of of another

Tags: animation, physics

I'm not sure how to use physics to make a mesh move on top of another, lets say a ball rolling on an uneven surface.

I'd like to be able to keyframe the moving object from point A to point B on the X and Y coordinates, but to have it follow the uneven surface of the Z axis.

Answer (score 2):

If you really do not need the Physics simulation, you could use a [Shrinkwrap](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Constraints/Relationship/Shrinkwrap) constraint. To use a shrink wrap constraint, Add an empty, then  parent the empty to the ball (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd>). Then add a Shrinkwrap constraint to the empty. Set the Shrinkwrap *Target* to the ground. For your case, you could set the *Shrinkwrap Type* to *Project*, then set it to *-Z*.

---

Keyframe your ball. Set the ball as a active rigid body (*Add Active*), in the *Physics* tab of the *Tool Shelf*. Then on your ground plane set it to a passive rigid body(*Add Passive*) in the *Physics* tab of the *Tool Shelf*. Play the animation from the beginning <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Left arrow</kbd>to jump to the beginning, and <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> to play.

Comment: David: Thanks for the prompt answer :) I'll try your suggestions asap.